# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist while running Selenium Test on Ubuntu

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have tried this code in eclipse :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class auto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/root/Desktop/jarselenium/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.easybooking.lk/login");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }
}
```

On execution I got this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /root/Desktop/jarselenium/geckodriver.exe
```

How can i set geckodriver location in ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using *Linux based System* while specifying the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* you have to trim the extension part i.e. `.exe` part as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/root/Desktop/jarselenium/geckodriver");
```

---

### Update

As you are still seeing the error ensure that :

1. *GeckoDriver* is present in the specified location.
2. *GeckoDriver* is having executable permission for non-root users. (chmod 777)
3. Execute your `@Test` as a non-root user.

Comment: same error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /root/Desktop/jarselenium/geckodrive.

Comment: @sanjan  Checkout my answer update and let me know the status. Don't miss the `e` at the fag end of `geckodriver`.

Comment: thz its work but  //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  if enble this line TimeUnit this is error

Comment: @sanjan Remove `implicitlyWait` totally from your `@Tests` as it is no more effective and in the long run you have to use only _WebDriverWait_